# Filtering in static block doesn't work

Tags: static-block

I added a new attribute 'featured_on_productpage' type yes/no and want to use something like  [this](http://indianicorange.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/product-listing-filter-by-attribute-in-cms-page/) on one of the cms pages.
I included this 
`{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="7" attribute_code=”featured_on_productpage” attribute_value=”1″  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` in the editor of the cms page, but instead of showing only products with the attribute set to 'yes' it shows all products of this category.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't even think it should work like you expected it to work.

Comment: Does that mean the code I found (the link) is wrong?

Comment: Yep, the code is definitely wrong. But I think the problem is that you didn't read that post. You focused on the code. The post actually asks a question. **IF that is possible**. The answer is 'not out of the box'.

Comment: So the only way is to do something like this http://www.atwix.com/magento/products-list-cms/ or this http://inchoo.net/magento/featured-products-on-magento-frontpage-tutorial/?

Comment: How can it be the "only way" if you listed 2 links? :). I'm sure there are more ways of doing it, but I would start with one of those. the guys and girls ar atwix and inchoo know what they are talking about.

Comment: :D ... ok maybe wrongly worded. As I wrote 'the only way' I meant 'only with extending things'. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this question would have an answer...
This is not possible out of the box.
you will need to create your own block that extends the `catalog/product_list` block and handles the additional attributes.

You need to rewrite the `_getProductCollection` method and make it look like this:

```
protected function _getProductCollection() 
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
       $this->_productCollection = parent::_getProductCollection(); //do what the parent class does
       //check if you should filter by an attribute
       if ($this->hasData('attribute_code') && $this->hasData('attribute_value')) {
           $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($this->getData('attribute_code'), $this->getData('attribute_value'));
       }
    }
    return $this->_productCollection();
}
```

Then you can use your block like this:

```
{{block type="[module]/product_list" category_id="7" attribute_code=”featured_on_productpage” attribute_value=”1″  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After rethinking the problem and discussing it with another developer I used another solution.
Instead of an attribute I use an additional category "featured" (to be exact I use one additional category for each existing category so I can also differentiate between them ... in my case no problem because the shop has and will have only a single-digit number of categories) and let display it on my page with this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="10" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I think the additional advantage of this solution is that you can see at a glance which product is in the featured category and which not (in the manage categories area).